# Unable to repair hard drive - due to volume assignment problem?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, repair, core-storage

Disk utility and fsck [terminal] both agree that there is problem with my HD. I am curious if someone can help me figure out how I can deal with the problem.

Terminal - Normal Mode

```
MacBook-Pro:~ MacBook-Pro$ sudo /sbin/fsck -fy  
Password:  
__** /dev/rdisk1__   
** Root file system  
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-285).  
** Verifying volume when it is mounted with write access.  
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.  
   __The volume name is Macintosh HD__  
** Checking extents overflow file.  
** Checking catalog file.  
   Incorrect block count for file 2015-08-27_EWSOperationActivity.log  
   (It should be 598 instead of 599)  
** Checking multi-linked files.  
** Checking catalog hierarchy.  
** Checking extended attributes file.  
** Checking volume bitmap.  
   Volume bitmap needs minor repair for under-allocation  
** Checking volume information.  
   Invalid volume free block count  
   (It should be 17451422 instead of 17222776)  
** The volume Macintosh HD cannot be repaired when it is in use.  
** The volume Macintosh HD could not be repaired.
```

When I use Disk Utility or `fsck` [Terminal] in Recovery Mode, it appears as though there is no problem.

Terminal - Recovery Mode

```
-bash-3.2# /sbin/fsck -fy  
__** /dev/rdiskls2__  
** Root file system  
     Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-285).  
** Checking non-journaled HFS Plus Volume.  
     __The volume name is OS X Base System__  
** Checking extents overflow file.  
** Checking catalog file.  
** Checking multi-linked files.  
** Checking catalog hierarchy.  
** Checking extended attributes file.  
** Checking volume bitmap.  
** Checking volume information.  
** The volume OS X Base System appears to be OK.
```

I suspect this is due to a disk assignment problem since the Volume ID/Names are not the same.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ MacBook-Pro$ diskutil list  
/dev/disk0  
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER  
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0  
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1  
   **2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         499.4 GB   disk0s2**  
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3  
/dev/disk1  
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER  
   **0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *499.1 GB   disk1**  
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2  
                                 CF5FFBF4-D1D2-4537-AF23-A03CAA5DBD19  
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

Here is the info re: Core Storage

```
MacBook-Pro:~ MacBook-Pro$ diskutil corestorage list  
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)  
|  
+-- Logical Volume Group CB946DA7-7697-4D60-9A9E-4FDD678AC852  
    =========================================================  
    Name:         Macintosh HD  
    Status:       Online  
    Size:         499418034176 B (499.4 GB)  
    Free Space:   4096 B (4.1 KB)  
    |  
    +-< Physical Volume FBF80BBF-91A2-4904-B27B-DBA839B33F85  
    |   ----------------------------------------------------  
    |   Index:    0  
    |   Disk:     disk0s2  
    |   Status:   Online  
    |   Size:     499418034176 B (499.4 GB)  
    |  
    +-> Logical Volume Family A27CF003-4591-4FE2-A683-3F64961BD8D0  
        ----------------------------------------------------------  
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked  
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS  
        Conversion Status:       Complete  
        Conversion Direction:    -none-  
        Has Encrypted Extents:   Yes  
        Fully Secure:            Yes  
        Passphrase Required:     Yes  
        |  
        +-> Logical Volume CF5FFBF4-D1D2-4537-AF23-A03CAA5DBD19  
            ---------------------------------------------------  
            Disk:                  disk1  
            Status:                Online  
            Size (Total):          499082485760 B (499.1 GB)  
            Conversion Progress:   -none-  
            Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)  
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD  
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD  
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Answer (score 1):

Executing `/sbin/fsck -fy` in Recovery Mode will verify/repair your recovery system (Base OS X System) instead of the corrupted CoreStorage Logical Volume:

> …
>   ** Checking volume information.
>   ** The volume **OS X Base System** appears to be OK.

Unlock - if necessary - and mount your main volume (Macintosh HD) first, then verify/repair it with Disk Utility.

Comment: I will try your suggestion and report back later. Thanks @klanomath

Answer (score 0):

The reported error is minor.
You haven't told us what kind of Mac or what disk it has.

I suspect there are a couple of bad sectors, which have been removed.
Try rebooting, and see if there is still a problem.

Comment: @Miliways; good point: MBP 15" mid-2014 2.5 I7 with 500 SSD. I tried to reboot but it does not change anything.